Tkinter: Assigning binds to a large number of widgets (frames) created by a loop function
I am developing a gallery display tool with Python's Tkinter which involves creating a lot of frames at once, each containing an image. This is achieved with 'while' or 'for' loops:
x = 0
while x < 10:
     tk.Frame(r, width=50, height=50, borderwidth=1, relief='solid', bg='purple').pack()
     x+=1

This works well since I don't need to store any of in it in a variable. However the issue is that I also want to bind an event to each one of these frames which doesn't work as intended:
import tkinter as tk

r = tk.Tk()

# This function switches the Frame's color
def change_color(wid):
    # This print function shows that only '.!Frame10' is being affected
    print(wid)

    if wid['bg'] == 'purple':
        wid['bg'] = 'green'

    elif wid['bg'] == 'green':
        wid['bg'] = 'purple'

# Frames are created by functions to allow binding & packing using a temporary reference
def frame():
    main = tk.Frame(r, width=50, height=50, borderwidth=1, relief='solid', bg='purple')
    # This bind triggers the function which affects the frame being left-clicked
    main.bind_all('<Button-1>', lambda a: change_color(main) )
    main.pack()

# This loop creates 10 instances of the frame
x = 0
while x < 10:
     frame()
     x+=1

r.mainloop()

The intended result is that each individual frame can be left-clicked to switch it's colors but instead only the last frame, dubbed ".!Frame10" switches color if any on the frames are clicked.
I read that you can sort of automate storing objects/functions in variables using dictionaries but it doesn't seem to work with me. This example I made returns " KeyError: '3' " which I don't understand.
import tkinter as tk

r = tk.Tk()

# This function switches the Frame's color
def change_color(x):
    # This print function shows that only '.!Frame10' is being affected
    print(x)

    if x['bg'] == 'purple':
        x['bg'] = 'green'

    elif x['bg'] == 'green':
        x['bg'] = 'purple'

dic = {}

# This loop creates frames and stores them in the dictionary above.
x = 1
while x < 3:
    dic[str(x)] = tk.Frame(r, width=50, height=50, borderwidth=1, relief='solid', bg='purple')
    dic[str(x)].bind_all('<Button-1>', lambda a: change_color(dic[str(x)]) )
    dic[str(x)].pack()
    x+=1

r.mainloop()

I did get it to work with dictionaries a few times but it gave the same result as above; only the last frame is changed.
Any help would be appreciated.

This question is similar to: tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This will solve your problem. Explanations given as comments inside the code
import tkinter as tk
r = tk.Tk()
r.geometry('500x700')

# This function switches the Frame's color
def change_color(wid):
    current_bg = wid.cget('bg') # use wid.cget()
    if current_bg == 'purple':
        wid.config(bg = 'green') # Use wid.config

    elif current_bg ==  'green': # use wid.cget()
        wid.config(bg = 'purple') # Use wid.config

def create_frames():       
    
    for x in range(10):
        frame = tk.Frame(r, width=50, height=50, borderwidth=1, relief='solid', bg='purple')
        frame.pack()

        # Pass the current frame as a default argument to fix late binding
        frame.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, current_frame=frame: change_color(current_frame))

           

create_frames()
r.mainloop()


Would it be nice if you use Warlus like this if current_bg := wid.cget('bg') == 'purple': and  elif current_bg := wid.cget('bg') == 'green':  instead of duplicates?

Not duplicating.Split into more steps for clearer understanding

For your case you can simply get the widget that triggers the event using the widget attribute of the event object:
# get the widget from the event object
main.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: change_color(e.widget)) 

PS: Suggest to use bind() instead of bind_all().
